# Stored Procedure issue

Tags: mysql

I am new to sql and most of my training is in MSSQL, however I am taking a class in MYSQL. I have a stored procedure that is giving me an issue. I have the delimiter set to //.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddComment
(
    name varchar(50),
    emailAddress varchar(50),
    Comments text
)
BEGIN
DECLARE ComName varchar(50);
DECLARE ComID int;


SELECT name into ComName;

SELECT ID into ComID from Commenters WHERE names = ComName;

if ComID = NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO COMMENTERS ('names', 'emailAddresses') values (name,   emailAddress);
        SELECT ID into ComID from Commenters WHERE names = ComName;
    END

    INSERT INTO COMMENTS ('commentersID', 'Comments') values (ComID, Comments);

END;
//
```

## EDIT

This is what I have now:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddComment
(
    Username varchar(50),
    UseremailAddress varchar(50),
    UserComment text
)
BEGIN
DECLARE ComName varchar(50);
DECLARE ComID int;


SELECT Username into ComName;

SELECT ID into ComID from Commenters WHERE names = ComName;

if ComID = NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO COMMENTERS(names,emailAddresses) values (Username, UseremailAddress);
        SELECT ID into ComID from Commenters WHERE names = ComName;
    END

    INSERT INTO COMMENTS(commentersID, Comments) values (ComID, UserComment);


END;
//
```

And the error I am getting is:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN INSERT INT
O COMMENTERS(names, emailAddresses) values (Username, Useremail' at line 1

Any Ideas?

Comment: what's the error that you're getting?

Comment: I am running through the schools command line: This is the error that is printing out. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN INSE
RT INTO COMMENTERS('names','emailAddresses') values (name, emailAddres' at line 2

Comment: try taking the quotes off of the column names, i.e. INSERT INTO COMMENTERS(names, emailAddresses) values(names, emailAddresses); To avoid confusion, you may want to name your parameters differently from the column names, for instance 'p_name' for the 'name' parameter..

Comment: Yeah I worried about that. The columns are plural and my parameters are not. Got me a little closer: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN INSER
T INTO COMMENTERS(names, emailAddresses) values (name, emailAddress);' at line 1

Comment: Change the parameter name. It's a cleaner way to code, and doesn't confuse those who come after (like _you_ in six weeks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are coding column names and values reversed in you insert statements.

It should be

```
 INSERT INTO COMMENTERS (name, emailAddress) values ('names', 'emailAddresses') ;
```

Comment: I was under the assumption that columns went before parameters. IE... INSERT INTO _tablename_ (_columns_) values (_parameter_); Is that wrong?

Comment: @ColeMietzner no you are correct, but that's not what you coded. Column names should **not** have quotes, values **should** have quotes (or be a variable of the proc)